# lossless frame extraction from video

Tags: ffmpeg, lossless

I have an mp4 video file with these characteristics:

[image: video description according to VLC]
-Encoder: Lavf58.29.100

I want to extract each frame as an image, with the following requirements:

- one image file is one frame (i.e., account for variable framerates to work in all cases),
- the image file has to be lossless TIFF.

I use Linux and would prefer Python to do this, but I can also use FFmpeg.

However, I have seen some other posts here, but they are either not-replied to or just need JPG format. I have read the [imwrite](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html) documentation (OpenCV) and saw that it is actually possible to export as TIFF (even with different bit-depths),  but I can't see an example of using that. I also do not know how to confirm if the exported TIFF is actually without compression.

The reason I need each frame as a lossless image file is that I need the images for further analysis in research, and I don't want to lose any information at this stage (the sequence of images is the starting 'raw material' of my analysis pipeline).

Comment: You don't need tiff. png or jpg at 100% will do just as well. It's not compression you need to avoid, it's lossy compression.

Comment: Thank you. Then I will try with `cv2.imwrite(name, frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 100])`

Answer (score 0):

---

After research and help from here and other places, I found 3 ways to do it.

**Pillow (Python)**

- Command: `img.save(output_filename,format='TIFF',compression='tiff_deflate',tiffinfo={})`
- Result: Generates 2246
  TIFF files (variable sizes, between 761 and 566 KiB)

**OpenCV (Python)**

- Command: `cv2.imwrite(name, frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION, 1])`
- Result: Generates 2246 TIFF files (6.4 MiB each one)

**ffmpeg (tested on Linux)**

- Command: ([see different ways](https://superuser.com/questions/1781258/avoid-duplicate-frames-in-ffmpeg))
- Result: Generates 2246 or 2247 TIFF files, depending on the exact command ([see different ways](https://superuser.com/questions/1781258/avoid-duplicate-frames-in-ffmpeg)). Each file is 2.8 MiB

---

**Edit 1**: The differences between file sizes in each option (e.g. 600 KiB vs 6.4 MiB vs 2.8 MiB) seem to be related to the compression used by different algorithms. I used [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) and found that in deed the compression is different: *uncompressed* (Python/OpenCV), *PackBits* (ffmpeg) and *Adobe Deflate* (Python/Pillow).

**Edit 2**: after further inspection and comparison, I observed that Python/Pillow (which uses *Adobe Deflate* method) also significantly changed the colors in the picture! I am unsure if this is due to the compression method or is something else done by Pillow.

Comment: Try to get details about the TIFF files via [`exiftool`](https://exiftool.org/). TIFFs can have different bit depth, different number of channels, different compression methods. You can even have JPEG inside a TIFF.

Comment: Thank you for a great suggestion! I used `exiftool` and found that in deed the compression is different: _uncompressed_ (Python/OpenCV), _PackBits_ (ffmpeg) and _Adobe Deflate_ (Python/Pillow).

Answer (score 0):

This ffmpeg command should do the trick for you:

```bash
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select=eq(n\,0),setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)" output_%08d.tif
```

Note: Your input is allready encoded in a lossy encoding, so you will have artifacts from the h264 codec.